# Multiple select for firebase

Tags: firebase

I am implementing simple facebook game and  have chosen firebase as BAAS which looks really cool and easy to use.
But I've stuck to question answer to which was not easy to find.
So here it is.

I need to show friends progresses to each other.
Like if userA has friend1 and friend2 friends in facebook, userA can see friend1 and friend2 progresses.

The structure is something like.

```
users/userA
   {
       progress : 'some progress'
   }

users/friend1
   {
       progress : 'some other progress'
   }

users/friend2 
   {
       progress : 'progress again'
   }
```

So I receive 'friend1' and 'friend2' from facebook and now I need to get their progresses from firebase.

Isn't that possible to get data by single query?
Should I make

```
`curl 'https://project-xxx.firebaseio.com/users.json?equalTo="FRIEND_NAME"'`
```

for each friend?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Firebase.

Firebase is asynchronous in nature. Your question indicates you may want to use a polling technique to get a users's friends progress.

You may want to consider letting Firebase do the heavy lifting for you; when a user's friend's progress changes, let Firebase tell you about it instead of polling for that change.

That's accomplished by setting up an observer on each friends node (or all nodes and filter in code). When a progress changes for the users being observed, your app will be notified.

Based on your firebase structure, here's an example, in Swift:

```
let thisUserRef = self.usersRef.childByAppendingPath("friend1")
//you could add observers for friend2, friend 3 etc

thisUserRef.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { snapshot in
   let progress = snapshot.value["progress"] as! String
   print(progress)
}
```

Once this code runs, any time friend1 has a change in their progress, the friend1 node will be delivered to your app and you can update the UI accordingly.

You can extrapolate from this up a level and observe the /users node in general. With that, all users progress changes are delivered to your app and you can filter out the ones that are not in user A's friends list.

It's more data but that may fit your use case.

The Firebase getting started guides used to contain great examples of how to do this but I am not seeing those examples available any longer. Maybe a Firebaser can provide a link to  the current code examples.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I see what you mean. But when user opens game on facebook it should display friends current progress. So for the first time I need to load the friends progress display it, and only after that I can subscribe to changes and show the updates dynamically.

Comment: My pleasure. If it helps, don't forget to accept the answer!